# Python SQLite3, как осуществить добавление данных в БД из полей ввода?

Tags: python, sql

Нужно добавить данные из полей ввода и combobox , но при передаче их значений через `get()` добавляются сами запросы `(self.entry_description.get() , self.combobox.get())`. Как это исправить?

```
cursor = sqlite3.connect('finance.db').cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES ('self.entry_description.get()', 'self.combobox.get()', 'self.entry_money.get()' )""")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Естественно, вы же вставляете в базу обычные строки, а не результаты вызова методов. Можно воспользоваться конкатенацией строк

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES ('"""
               + self.entry_description.get() + """', '""" 
               + self.combobox.get() + """', '"""
               + self.entry_money.get() + """')""")
```

Или f-строками, если у вас Python версии 3.6 и большей

```
cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES ('{self.entry_description.get()}', '{self.combobox.get()}', '{self.entry_money.get()}' )""")
```

Но лучше всего использовать *prepared statements*

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO albums(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'''

cursor.execute(sql, (self.entry_description.get(),
                     self.combobox.get(),
                     self.entry_money.get()))
```

Кроме удобства использования, это обезопасит вас от [sql injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).