# Ускорение вставки значений в базу данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, postgresql

Делаю SQL запрос на вставку. Как его можно ускорить?

```
for i, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    values = ','.join(transform_types(row[1].values.tolist()))
    try:
        cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO telemetry ({columns}) VALUES({values});')
    except Exception as e:
        self.__conn.rollback()
        print(list(zip(columns.split(','), values.split(','))), e)
    self.__conn.commit()
```

Comment: Отправить одним запросом

Comment: @AzizUmarov т.е. сформировать огромную строку и пихнуть её в `execute`?

Comment: Делать вставки в одной транзакции.

Comment: [Populating a Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/populate.html) - офф документация

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас тут сразу несколько проблем.

Первое, это комит после каждой записи. На HDD диске с 7200 оборотами, даже теоретический максимум - 120 транзакций в секунду, поэтому комит после каждой вставки очень плохо для производительности.

Дальше, нельзя использовать конструирование параметров в виде строки, т.е. речь о переменной `values` и ее подстановке `{values}`. Это во-первых, уязвимо к SQL-injection, а, во-вторых, плохо для производительности, так как не используются prepared statements.

Самый быстрый способ вставки это использовать команду postgres `COPY`. psycopg2 выставляет ее через функции `copy_from` и `copy_expert`. Там код посложнее чем наивная вставка или даже `execute_batch`, но того стоит. Я наблюдал ускорение и до того правильного кода в 100 раз после перехода на `COPY`.

Смысл в том, что используется низкоуровневый протокол постгрес для вставки, который хорошо оптимизирован как раз для чтения/записи большого количества данных.

Comment: Как мне сейчас быстро огородиться от инъекции без copy?

Comment: @hedgehogues - параметризованный запрос. И лучше задать отдельный вопрос про это.

Comment: Есть много таких вопросов уже. Быстро нашел вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883764/python-sqlite3-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/883775#883775

Comment: @RomanKonoval если я воспользуюсь COPY, не огребу ли я проблем с коллизиями?

Comment: При коллизии откатится вся операция. Пока еще нет в copy поддержки `on conflict do nothing`. Обходной путь - это вставлять в промежуточную таблицу, а потом уже из нее делать вставку тех записей, которые не конфликтуют.

Comment: _Первое, это комит после каждой записи_ - следующее после этой цитаты пояснение не совсем верное. Упор только на производительность, а более важным критерием при определени, когда фиксировать тарнзакцию - консистентность изменений.

Comment: `На HDD диске с 7200 оборотами, даже теоретический максимум - 120 транзакций в секунду` - поспорю. Коммит не означает однозначную запись на диск. Есть write ahead log. Вот в [официальной документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/wal-intro.html) написано: `we do not need to flush data pages to disk on every transaction commit` и чуть дальше `when the server is processing many small concurrent transactions, one fsync of the log file may suffice to commit many transactions`

Comment: @TotalPusher вы неправильно интерпретируете то, что там написано. Там речь о том, что не нужно блоки данных записывать на диск. И блоки данных действительно пишутся позже (в идеале асинхронно, либо во время обработки запроса, если не хватает места в буферном кеше). А вот WAL как раз нужно писать на диск для каждой транзакции и пока flush на диск не произошел commit не считается успешным. Именно эта необходимость делать запись на диск + скорость вращения диск накладывают верхнее ограничение на макс. количество транзакций.

Comment: Что касается `one fsync of the log file may suffice to commit many transactions` - тут речь о разных клиентах. Для случая одного клиента делающего вставку в один поток - это не применимо. И всегда будет одна транзакция - один fsync (commit - блокирующий вызов и клиент не может продолжать) и соответсвенно лимит 120 транзакций. Стоит уточнить, конечно, этот лимит для одного клиента. Каждый клиент может делать до 120 транзакций (если сервер потянет по ресурсам).

Comment: Кстати, `executemany` работает медленнее, чем нативная конкатенация строк

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase')
df.to_sql("telemetry", engine, if_exists="append")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

Можно ещё [пакетом](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql)

Пример из ссылки

```
cursor.executemany("""
            INSERT INTO staging_beers VALUES (
                %(id)s,
                %(name)s,
                %(tagline)s,
                %(first_brewed)s,
                %(description)s,
                %(image_url)s,
                %(abv)s,
                %(ibu)s,
                %(target_fg)s,
                %(target_og)s,
                %(ebc)s,
                %(srm)s,
                %(ph)s,
                %(attenuation_level)s,
                %(brewers_tips)s,
                %(contributed_by)s,
                %(volume)s
            );
        """, all_beers)
```

Или пример с батчем

```
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor, """
            INSERT INTO staging_beers VALUES (
                %(id)s,
                %(name)s,
                %(tagline)s,
                %(first_brewed)s,
                %(description)s,
                %(image_url)s,
                %(abv)s,
                %(ibu)s,
                %(target_fg)s,
                %(target_og)s,
                %(ebc)s,
                %(srm)s,
                %(ph)s,
                %(attenuation_level)s,
                %(brewers_tips)s,
                %(contributed_by)s,
                %(volume)s
            );
        """, all_beers)
```

Comment: Да, я такой вариант рассматривал. Но строка космических размеров получается. 20000 строк. Пакетом как? Батчами слать?

Comment: 20000 можно разделить на разумные кусочки

Comment: Под пакетами что подразумевается?

Comment: Обновил ответ посмотрите может поможет

Comment: В чём отличие от того, чтобы сформировать строку?

Comment: Посмотрите по ссылке там есть и execute_batch

Comment: Метод executemany позволяет выполнить одну команду SQL для последовательности параметров (или для итератора).

Comment: C `executemany` только одна проблема, что он практически такой же (если не медленнее) чем простая вставка по одному. В той же статье это тоже написано.

Comment: Есть ещё и бас смотрите в ответ

Comment: Или посмотрите на статью в ответе