# Как оптимизировать вставку в БД вложенной древовидной структурой?

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql9.6

Есть многоуровневая древовидная структура, получаемая с клиента

```
[
    'name' => 'text1'
    'children' => [
        ['name' => 'text2', 'children' => []],
        [
            'name' => 'text3'
            'children' => [
                ['name' => 'text4', 'children' => []],
                ['name' => 'text5', 'children' => []],
                ['name' => 'text6', 'children' => []],
            ]
        ],
    ]
]
```

Стандартная: узел дерева и его потомки, с бесконечной вложенностью.

Как можнозанести все эти записи в БД оптимизированно? Наибольшей эффективностью.

У меня на уме только два способа:

1. Делать вставки рекурсивно в БД. Т.е. вставляется родитель, берётся у него `id`, потом вставляются его потомки с `parent_id`, который только что получили, у них тоже получаем `id` и вставляем их потомков с `parent_id` указывающим на них.

   Это легко сделать, но, боюсь, что это очень неэффективно, т.к. по сути, на 100 узлов будет 100 `INSERT`'ов (ну или каждую пачку детей можно через один INSERT записывать, но всё равно неэффективно).
2. Взять последний `id` в базе, даже заблокировать таблицу для записи, рассчитать все идентификаторы заранее и вписать их в массив. И уже одним инсертом вставить в БД.

   Этот способ мне не нравится, потому что надо блокировать всю таблицу на время рассчёта идентификаторов на сервере и их вставки.

Есть ли ещё способы вставки такой структуры?

Comment: Для работы с деревьями в БД можете погуглить технологии _Nested Sets_ и _Closure Tables_. И есть масса библиотек для их реализации. Есть плюсы, минусы и подводные камни)))

Comment: Да, я знаю про Nested Sets, но сейчас используется классика и по-другому нельзя. Поэтому нужен способ для него. Но вроде для nested sets тоже надо указывать какие-либо номера слева и справа от узла, так что проблема всё равно же останется, разве нет?

Comment: Тогда скомбинируйте свои способ 1 и 2. Вместо автоинкрементного числового id используйте uuid. Сгенерируйте их в своем коде, а потом запишите всю пачку

Comment: К сожалению проект уже давно идёт и в БД id'шники  с автоинкрементом :-(  Кстати, а uuid не медленней для поиска по БД будет, чем числовой индекс (primary key)? Если других вариантов реально не будет, может быть можно будет подумать в эту сторону :-))

Comment: в постгре есть тип поля uuid, если использовать его, то не сильно повлияет, поскольку хранится в бинарном виде. Если сохранять в текстовом виде, то замедлится

Comment: вы возьмите способ2, но вставьте во временную таблицу. а потом за раз перенесите все в нужную

Comment: в первом способе кстати на 100 узлов будте не 100 инсертов. за раз можно вносить всех детей с одного уровня.

Comment: Во втором способе вовсе не обязательно блокировать таблицу. Используйте один и тот же sequence для генерации id при любой вставке, тогда такая генерация не потребует блокировки, даже если делаете ее предварительно. Что касается самой вставки, то используйте batch insert, а еще лучше COPY. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1175443/218971) описано для питона. О каких объемах данных идет речь?

Comment: @teran " а потом за раз перенесите все в нужную" - не совсем понимаю чем отличаться будет от того, что я сразу буду вставлять данные в нужную таблицу, ведь я уже сгенерирую идентификаторы. И при вставке во временную там же должны как-то соблюдаться те же id, что и в оригинальной? или надо вставлять id + N, где N - последний id в оригинальной таблице? А по поводу вставки 100 - да, будет не 100 операций, об этом в скобке упомянула :)

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA объём небольшой, может быть максимум по 400-500 узлов (пока гипотетически :) ) В большей степени в районе 100. Посмотрю про copy, спасибо Про сиквенсы тоже сейчас подумаю)

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA а про Используйте один и тот же sequence  вы имели в виду чтобы во временную вставлять изначально, используя сиквенс от оригинальной таблицы? а потом данные из временной вставить в оригинальную. Или что-то другое?

Comment: Не нужно временной таблицы. Вот хотите вы вставить дерево, скажем 500 записей. Чтоб можно было их вставить пачкой с помощью COPY нужно знать идентификаторы узлов, чтоб можно было указать идентификатор узла и идентификатор родителя. Используйте sequnence чтоб сгенерировать 500 идентификаторов, и теперь у вас есть все значения полей для вставки. Храните их просто в памяти.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA сложновато. в том плане что это же надо в одной транзакции делать: открыть транзакцию, сгенерировать идентификаторы, построить данные и вставить. Закрыть транзакцию. Но. если по какой-то причине операция не удалась, то надо эти идентификаторы откатить получается? Будет, конечно, иногда странные записи в таком случае, что соседние узлы будут на расстоянии в сотни идентификаторов в БД. Разве нет?

Comment: Для генерации идентификаторов с помощью sequence транзакция не нужна. Откатывать в случае неудачи не нужно да и не получится, если использовать sequence, это нормальная практика, тут за скорость генерации мы платим невозможностью откатить. Что касается идентификаторов не под ряд. Это же синтетические идентификаторы, какая разница какие у них значения? Кто их и где будет видеть?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA поняла, спасибо. как раз нашла как сгенерировать идентификаторы через `select nextval('mytable_seq') from generate_series(1,3);`  буду пробовать :)